# How do I stream Twilio audio to a script?

Tags: twilio, sip

I would like to set up a script on an AWS server that can "listen to" audio from a Twilio call.

My thought was to create a conference call that dials a SIP endpoint that I'm running on AWS, so when the user calls it forwards the call to this SIP endpoint. I don't fully understand SIP, though, and I'm not sure how to get an audio stream from the connection.

So far, I set up a drachtio server and connected a node script to it -- I can see the invite coming in, which is great -- but how do I actually pull the audio stream out?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to point to the solution that you found?

Comment: unfortunately, I never was able to figure out a solution to this :(

Comment: did you have any luck using drachtio as suggested by the answer below?

Comment: negative :(. I gave up on the project because it turned out to be so complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you will need to use a media framework as well. Drachtio has a media framework that works with Freeswitch (https://github.com/davehorton/drachtio-fsmrf). You could probably use that to determine when the media portion of the call has started or media was negotiated, or whatever it is you want to do with the media.